# Flutter: different app icon and app name depending on release/production build or debug/development build?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, build, release

Is there any way of changing the app's name and/or the app's icon depending on the building mode selected (development or production) ?

```
release mode -> Logo A & <app_name>
debug mode -> Logo B & <app_name>-dev
```

I've been looking but could't find anything —or didn't search at the right place. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I used a flutter feature called flavors which works for Android and iOS.

Here is the guide I followed : https://youtu.be/Vhm1Cv2uPko

For devs using VS Code, I created a VS Code config file to make launching the apps in the different flavors easier :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Development",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
            "args" : ["--flavor", "development", "--target", "lib/main_dev.dart"],
            // ? Keep flutterMode
            "flutterMode": "debug",
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Production",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main_prod.dart",
            "args": ["--flavor", "production", "--target", "lib/main_prod.dart"],
            // ? Keep flutterMode
            "flutterMode": "release",
        },
        {
            "name": "Run All Tests",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./test/",
        },
    ]
}
```

This subject is treated in the video linked.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to build an Android application, there are several steps that you should follow

Please, note that if you want to keep both applications in one device, you should change the package name of the app, that can be done easily by adding a suffix inside the app's level `build.gradle` `projectName/android/app/build.gradle` a suffix for the build type of the debug mode like this:

```html
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
```

For the app's name:

1. In your project's folder there is a folder named `android/app/src`, inside it, you will find three more folders [image]
2. Move inside this `debug` directory and add a folder named `res`, in there you will be able to store the resources that will be used in development(debug) mode and inside it create a directory named `values`
3. Create a file named `strings.xml`, in this folder, you can store your dynamic app's name
4. Here you will define your app's name, copy inside it the code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app_name-DEV</string>

</resources>
```

4. Also you will have to add the `string.xml` file in the same path in the main folder(below the debug folder) inside the same path `main/res/values` inside it, you should apply a different name for the key `app_name` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app_name-DEV</string>

</resources>
```

5. in the main folder, there is a file named: `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside it remove the line `android:name="${applicationName}"` because it will cause few conficts and change the line: `android:label:"some_label"` -> `android:label="@string/app_name"`
6. From this file, copy the whole  tag, and paste it inside the debug's folder `AndroidManifest.xml` and before the line `android:label="@string/app_name"` add this line `tools:replace="android:label"`, this will enable the debug's manifest to override the app's name.

-> `projectFolder/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`
[image]

For the app's icon:

1. in the `projectFolder/android/app/src/debug/res` you should create the mipmap folders(you can copy them from the `projectFolder/android/app/src/main/res` folder and then to modify the icons)
   [image]
2. inside them, you should add a the icon for the development mode with the same, for this purpose, you can follow the following package [flutter_launcer_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) (Please make sure that in the end you will run this command: `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` , but still you can add them manually)

That's all.
Hope I was enough thorough :)
If you have any questions, let me know

Comment: Thanks ! It worked for android but I finally used a flutter feature called flavors (for Android & iOS). Here is the guide I followed : https://youtu.be/Vhm1Cv2uPko